# How to remove duplicate values from dropdownlist | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

```dart
child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: DropdownButton(
    value: selectedCategory,
    hint: Text(
      'Select Category',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
    ),
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
      color: Colors.grey[600],
    ),
    items: jobFairData.map(
      (list) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(
            list['categoryName'],
            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
          ),
          value: list['categoryId'].toString(),
        );
      },
    ).toList(),
    onChanged: (value) => setState(() => selectedCategory = value),
  ),
),
```

This is my Dropdown list code, with the values coming from an API. The problem is that the values from the API contain duplicates. This makes the app crash.

How can I avoid the duplicate values and show the data to Dropdown list?

Comment: .toSet is also not working

Answer (score 1):

If your data is something like this:

```json
final jobFairData = [
  {
    'categoryId': 1,
    'categoryName': 'Category 1',
  },
  {
    'categoryId': 2,
    'categoryName': 'Category 2',
  },
  {
    'categoryId': 2,
    'categoryName': 'Category 2',
  },
  {
    'categoryId': 3,
    'categoryName': 'Category 3',
  },
];
```

Then, `jobFairData.toSet()` will not work because the two identical items `{'categoryId': 2, 'categoryName': 'Category 2'}` are not equal, being two different objects.

There are a lot of solutions to remove identical items from such a list. Here are a few:

### Using `toSet()` on the `categoryId`:

```dart
final ids = jobFairData.map((d) => d['categoryId']).toSet();
filteredJobFairData.value = jobFairData
  ..retainWhere((element) => ids.remove(element['categoryId']));
```

### Transforming your list in a map {categoryId: categoryName}

```dart
jobsFairData.fold<Map<String, String>>({}, (acc, curr) => acc..[curr['categoryId']] = curr['categoryName']);
```

The way you define your `items`:

```dart
items: jobFairData.entries
  .map((category) => DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text(
      category.value,
      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
    ),
    value: category.key,
  ))
  .toList(),
```

### Defining a proper Category class and using `toSet()`:

Domain Model Class, using [freezer package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed):

```dart
@freezed
abstract class Category with _$Category {
  const factory Category({String id, String name}) = _Category;

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CategoryFromJson(json);
}
```

Once you have such a class, you can get a `List<Category` from JSON data and then use the `toSet().toList()` trick to remove duplicate:

```dart
final jobFairData = jsonData.map((json) => Category.fromJson(json)).toSet().toList();
```

*Note: Doing this, you might lose the order of your original data.*

The main benefit of this solution is that your categories are now `Category` objects and not generic `Map<String, dynamic`. Your `DropDownButton`'s `items` definition is more robust:

```dart
items: jobFairData
  .map(
    (category) => DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(
        category.name,
        style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
      ),
      value: category.id,
    ),
  )
  .toList(),
```